# Converting zipcodes into US statenames using R

Tags: r, sas

Is there any function or easy, fast way to convert US zipcodes into state names using R. For this we have `zipstate()` function in SAS. 
In R, I tried this as:

```
library(zipcode)
newzips = as.data.frame.factor(zipcode[,1])

for(i in 1:nrow(dmefzip)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(zipcode)){
  if(dmefzip[i,1]== (newzips[j,1]) ){
    dmefzip[i,"state"] = zipcode[j,3]
    break
  }   
}
}
```

It is working but as there are around 35000 rows in my data, it is taking hours.
Please suggest some way. Thanks!

Comment: Zipcodes do not map to states. They do not fall into that geographical / spatial hierarchy. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code#Secondary_regional_prefixes_.28123xx.29_and_local_ZIP_codes_.2812345.29) and [here](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/webatlas/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh dear that double loop is really inefficient. First of all for a single zip code it would be much faster to simply get the matching state by doing `zipcode$state[zipcode$zip %in% YOURZIPCODEHERE]`

for a whole bunch of zip codes using `match` would serve your needs better.

`dmefzip$state = zipcode$state[match(dmefzip[,1],zipcode$zip)]`

Comment: As an alternative to the match function, you could do (this is actually the same function but a different syntax) `zipcode$state[dmefzip[,1] %in% zipcode$zip]`

Comment: @Matthew this will only work if the order in `dmefzip` is the same as the order in `zipcode$zip` though.

Comment: actually I should have put that the other way around.  As I typed it, it would only work if the two lists were the same size AND the order was the same.  It should be `zipcode$state[zipcode$zip %in% dmefzip[,1]]` which should work no matter the order or sizes.

Comment: @OganM thanks a lot for both the approaches. Really appreciate it.